# Fetching a list of parent entities with a filtered collection of children in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, projection

So I've been stuck on this problem for about half a day so I am wondering if I am just over-complicating things.

My application has three different Java object classes: Grandparent, Parent, and Child. Each Grandparent contains a List of Parents, and each Parent contains a List of Children. Child has an "isWellBehaved" property, which is a boolean.

We are using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate in order to map the data to a database. Our application contains a lot of nested entities and circular relationships and we are relying on projections to keep our request size down.

**The Problem:** given a grandparent id, I want to return a list of all Parents (as projections). I want each of the Parents to contain a list of Child projections, but only if the Child is well behaved. The rest of the children in the collection should be filtered out from the collection.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this? We are not using **Hibernate filters** at the moment and I am not keen on introducing them as we are not likely to need them anywhere else (either way, would it be suited for this purpose?). I have used **JPA Criteria API predicates** (very little) but find it difficult to adapt that to this particular scenario. Is a **native query** the way to go? I've started going in that direction but am having some issues mapping all the fields to our Spring entity due to all the nested dependencies so just want to make sure I am even headed in the right direction before I continue.

My (simplified) parent entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent"
public class Parent {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="parent_id")
    Integer id;

    Integer grandparentId; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    List<Child> children;
}
```

Child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child"
public class Child {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="child_id")
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    Parent parent;

    boolean isWellBehaved; 
}
```

Parent repository interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = ParentProjection.class)
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaProjectionRepository<Parent, Integer, ParentProjection> {

    List<ParentProjection> findAllByGrandparent_Id(Integer grandpaId);
}
```

Comment: Why not simply load all well-behaved children and then group them by parent (in Java) as a map of parent to list of children? Not as pretty as having a Parent entity with only filtered children but the same data without the need of loading Children that would be filtered out later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Where annotation of hibernate on collection. It will be something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent"
public class Parent {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="parent_id")
    Integer id;

    Integer grandparentId; 

    @Where(clause = "isWellBehaved=true")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    List<Children> children;
}
```

Comment: This looks like something that could work, except that, in some other cases, I need the collection to contain all Children. Do you know how would I go about achieving that?

Comment: I think you should declare another similar collection variable with different name and without @Where annotation. Make association lazy for both variables and fetch whichever suits your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

As you have said:

> I want each of the Parents to contain a list of Child projections, but only if the Child is well behaved.

```
List<childerns>allChilderns=parentsList.stream().map(parent>dao.findchildernByParentId()).collect(Collectors.List());

allChilderns.stream().filter(childern->childern.isWellBehaved()==true).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1. Get all the parents by GrandParentId--the one which you are doing.
2. Once you got all the parents,for each parent findchildernByParentId.
3. and then filter out the childern on the basis of condition.

Let me know:)

Comment: Why load all the data into memory to apply the filter when it could be done at the database level?

Comment: How would I return a list of Parents though? I cannot set the Children property because the Parents I get back from the database are only Projections, which are not modifiable. This is the bit that I have been struggling with the most.

Comment: Is there any chance you can return the list of entities instead of projection and then when you filter out the result then may be create another projection just for returning.

Comment: This would not work for queries with Pageable parameter as the parent rows are repeated based on the child rows and result in wrong pageable implementation.